# Testing Hubot locally in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, hubot

Hi Stackoverflow community,

Well the thing is that I'm working on a script for hubot. **Before starting to code I'm trying to test some hubot commands in the command line** (I already did it in Windows but for some reasons I've to change to Ubuntu environment to start to code this brand new custom hubot) I'd like to be able to write in the terminal `>Hubot PING` and get a response `PONG` to start to work.

Till now I've already installed Node.js through `nodenv` https://github.com/OiNutter/nodenv and I tested my node `>node -v`, got `v0.10.22`. I forked my hubot and cloned locally and then apply `~./hubot> npm install` to get all the dependencies and everything seems OK. Then I went to the installation folder `>cd node_modules/hosted-hubot` which has a folder called **bin**, inside the **hubot** folder.

So, till this point everything  seemed OK and I tried to do in the command line: `./bin/hubot` and I'm not able to run hubot locally, it gave me: **nodenv: version `v0.8' is not installed**. I tried to install an older version of node **0.8** and got the same message.

***So that's it, hope you guys can help me to try to test my hubot locally***

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Make it more clear: list ubuntu version, how you install hubot and nodenv. Ubuntu shall be the easily platform to play with hubot, or try nodejs instead nodenv first.

Comment: I made a fresh install and I instal node.js without nodenv and everything works properly. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fresh install and I instal node.js without nodenv and everything works properly. It may not be the better solution but it was what I did.